# How can I read a text file and write its values to an array

Tags: c#, file, streamreader, streamwriter

I have a text file with values and I need to read them.  The first line is the size of my array and the second line has values that I need to put into to an array.

[image: input file]

My `main` looks like:

```
public static void Main()
{
    int n,i=0,k=1;
    var plik_wejsciowy = new StreamReader("In0201.txt");
    StreamWriter plik_wyjsciowy = new StreamWriter("Out0201.txt");
    string[] wejscie = plik_wejsciowy.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    n = int.Parse(wejscie[0]);
    int[] tab = new int[n];
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        tab[i] = int.Parse(wejscie[k]);
        k++;
    }

    plik_wyjsciowy.Close();
   }
```

I don't really know what to do and where I'm making a mistake.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. can you please be more specific about what exactly your _problem_ is? i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Your question describes two lines in the input file, but you're only reading one. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: so how do i get to the second line ?

Comment: Why do you split the line on spaces? Post an example of your file

Comment: i added image of input file, the values can change and can be more of them

Answer (score 0):

We can make life easier; you don't really need to use the first line to track how many lines are in the file; you can just read the lines into an array (skip the first if it's only a line counter) then parse the rest and turn them into an array:

```
var x = File.ReadAllLines(path).Skip(1).Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

If you switch the first line being a counter of lines, remove the `Skip(1)`